# jQuery .slideToggle Usage

Tags: jquery

I am trying to place an anchor tag inside an article element that has the jQuery .slideToggle function attached to it.

This is the html:

```
<section id="recent_articles">

<article>

<img src="images/image1.jpg">
<h1>Insert title here</h1>
<p>Insert text here followed by an anchor tag<a href=#>Read More</a></p>

</article>

</section>

The jQuery looks like this:

$( "#recent_articles > article" ).click(function(e) {

        $(this).children("p").slideToggle(1000);
        $(this).toggleClass("open");

    });
```

I understand that the jQuery is "activating" whenever the article element is clicked (including the image element) and the paragraph is sliding down and up as instructed.

This means however that the anchor element is not accessible as it responds to jQuery and not the href attribute.

Using jQuery, how would I access the anchor element so that it responds with default link behavior and not the .slideToggle function.

I am very VERY new at using jQuery so any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: So you basically want to put a link inside that anchor, right? It should navigate to some content inside the same page but you want it to prevent to trigger the animate, right?

Comment: Correct, except that the link anchor should go to a new page. At the moment, clicking a link inside the paragraph just triggers the .slideToggle function.

Comment: Strange, it should navigate in any case... unless you're usign some `return false` or `event.preventDefalt()` somewhere...

Comment: Sorry,  e.preventDefault(); IS being used to stop the page jumping back up but I didn't think it would affect what I am trying to do. Since I am using the  e.preventDefault(); to stop it from jumping up when accessed under the fold, how would I make the anchor link work normally again?

Comment: If you're navigating to another page, your last concern should be *the page jumping to-top*, which is the default behavior **only** if you use #hash anchors; if you set a valid address like `a href="article1.html"` you don't have any more problems to fix and your code (removing the e.preventDefault()) should work as expected. (making my answer pretty useless :D )

Comment: A small tip: while developping, instead of setting href to `#`, you can do `a href="javascript:;"`

Comment: Thank you! It is working without the prevent default but there is an anchor tag being used to "show / hide" an intro paragraph as well. But this definitely helps me to get closer to the correct behavior!

Comment: You're welcome Nicole

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On click you can watch on the event.target Element (the one who called the event) **tagName**,
if it's not an anchor `"A"` than do the thing

```
$( "#recent_articles > article" ).click(function(ev) {
  if(ev.target.tagName!=="A"){
    $(this).children("p").slideToggle(1000);
    $(this).toggleClass("open");
  }
});
```

otherwise you can do it like you already do just adding another function bound to the `a` element that will **prevent the click event to propagate** (*bubble up*) to the `article`:

```
$( "#recent_articles > article" ).click(function(e) {
    $(this).children("p").slideToggle(1000);
    $(this).toggleClass("open");
}).find('a').click(function(e){ // find `a` inside `article` and on click...
   e.stopPropagation();         // don't propagate the event up to `article`
});
```

P.S: your function can be also a bit shorter like:

```
$( "#recent_articles > article" ).click(function(e) {
    $(this).toggleClass("open").children("p").slideToggle(1000);
}).find('a').click(function(e){
   e.stopPropagation();
});
```